# Performing a T-test to check a column in two different csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, statistics

I've got 2 csv files look similar to this:

```
date,high,low,precip
1-Jan,43,41,0
2-Jan,50,25,0
3-Jan,51,25,0
4-Jan,44,25,0
5-Jan,36,21,0
6-Jan,39,20,0
7-Jan,47,21,0.04
8-Jan,30,14,0
9-Jan,30,12,0
10-Jan,35,12,0
11-Jan,42,15,0
12-Jan,55,29,0
13-Jan,57,29,0
14-Jan,61,33,0
15-Jan,52,46,0.1
```

I need to perform a T-test on the "high" column, and I haven't found many ways to do this.  I've already imported the sum using this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re, csv
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
high_mean = round(pd.read_csv(r'2010-Jan-June.csv', usecols=['high'], squeeze=True).mean(), 1)
high_mean17 = round(pd.read_csv(r'2017-Jan-June.csv', usecols=['high'], squeeze=True).mean(), 1)
```

But I'm not sure how to use the data I've got there to run through the t-test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are in the right track

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
high_mean = pd.read_csv(r'2010-Jan-June.csv', usecols=['date','high'], squeeze=True).set_index('date')
high_mean17 = pd.read_csv(r'2017-Jan-June.csv', usecols=['date','high'], squeeze=True).set_index('date')

ttest_ind(high_mean.values,high_mean17.values)
```

Base on the doc *The arrays must have the same shape, except in the dimension corresponding to axis (the first, by default)*

So before runing through the t-test, you should make sure 2017 and 2010 have same length of data point. I am using `pd.concat` here to achieve the inner join

```
s=pd.concat([high_mean,high_mean17],axis=1,join='inner')

high_mean=s.iloc[:,0]
high_mean17=s.iloc[:,1]
```

Comment: It's definitely the same number.  The files only have data from Jan 1 - June 30, one from 2010, one from 2017.  Any reason I need the date column?

Comment: Also, oddly enough, @Wen, I'm getting a `NameError: name 'stats' is not defined` error.

Comment: @ArchivistG ok , you can do ttest_ind , after you `from scipy.stats import ttest_ind`